# Viewing object attributes with tab completion in sublimerepl python

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

In the IDLE interpreter in Python, you can see a drop-down list of an object's attributes by typing the object's name, then period, then hitting TAB.

Is it possible to get similar functionality with sublimerepl?

I've tried the different autocomplete packages, but they don't appear to make this happen.

Comment: SublimeCodeIntel works quite well for Python, if you give it a chance (or several chances) to properly index your site-packages, and you set it up properly. I've been using it with ST3 and IPython in SublimeREPL and it works great.

Comment: SublimeCodeIntel has definitely come the closest and maybe I haven't let it index long enough or I don't have my paths quite right. Ideally, I'd like the drop-down to only list the attributes/methods that are associated w/ the object, but right now it seems to be showing a standard set of attributes no matter what the object is.

Answer (score 0):

So there are many different packages, Andy's package being my favorite. None provide every method for a given function but try hitting "ctrl-space" after the period to see what's available!

Link:

https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/AndyPython